# Computing a complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

> Let $\gamma(t) = te^{it}$. What is $\gamma'(2\pi)$?

My incorrect answer was: $2+4\pi$.

Please, tell me what I did wrong and how to solve this correctly

Comment: How can we tell what you did wrong when you don't show us how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\gamma'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \left[te^{it}\right]
 = t \frac{d}{dt} \left[e^{it}\right] + e^{it} \frac{d}{dt}[t]
 = ite^{it} + e^{it} = e^{it}[1+it]
$$
What happens when you evaluate at $t=2\pi$?